# Data Transfer from Oracle to Postgres using Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, oracle, data-transfer

We need to **load historical data(>10M) from Oracle to Postgres**. We thought of using Pandas to read from Oracle into a Pandas DF and load the DF into Postgres. But team suggests it will take lot of time and could be better if there's a way to load directly from Oracle to Postgres without the DF. Could you please suggest some better approach for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Using a foreign data wrapper is probably a lot faster

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Its new to us, will go through the foreign data wrapper concept and try the implementation..

Comment: Are you doing this just once or will this be happening regularly? Can you do something simple like just dump the data into a text file and bulk load that into Postgres?

Comment: Yea its an one time load.. we're not expecting any incremental load as of now.. so will try your suggestion as well, thanks!